# Windows File Explorer Forward Slash Paths

Tags: windows

Not all path's but most paths on Windows can actually be written in the historically original `/` instead of `\`.

For example `C:\Users\a\Desktop` can be written as `C:/Users/a/Desktop/`

The problem is Windows Explorer doesn't display this by default - ever.

Is there a feasible Windows Explorer that does this or alternative with maybe autohotkey to achieve this functionality?

Comment: You want AHK to change the path when you click it at the top in windows explorer?

Comment: @CodyG. no when you press ctrl+L

Comment: @CodyＧ yes that could also work.

Comment: Wow this is old, but you could (in AHK) 1. `F4`, to select the link, 2. `ctrl + c` to get the link, 3. `modify clipboard` (via ahk) to replace `\` with `/`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SIGMA](https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager)?

With it you can use the forward slash <kbd>/</kbd>

... among other [features](https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/wiki/Features).

[image]